# MySql - TIME() function not working in a CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the TIME() function in a case statement, like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE(datetime_column) = CURDATE() THEN TIME(datetime_column) ELSE datetime_column END as datetime_column
FROM my_table;
```

but I'm getting '0000-00-00 00:00:00' when the case evaluate = CURDATE().

If I try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '2016-04-06' = CURDATE() THEN TIME('2016-04-06 07:28:04') ELSE '2016-04-06 07:28:04' END as datetime_column;
```

I'm getting 07:28:04

Also, if I try the same query using DATE_FORMAT(), like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE(datetime_column) = CURDATE() THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime_column, '%H:%i:%s') ELSE datetime_column END as datetime_column FROM my_table;
```

I'm getting the time as well.

Any ideas?

Data Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `inserted_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('five','2016-04-06 12:37:07')
,('four','2016-04-06 12:36:16')
,('one','2016-04-06 12:30:37')
,('three','2016-04-06 12:32:05')
,('two','2016-04-06 12:31:32');
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: This sounds like MySQL having difficulty casting one or the other of the time or datetime because it is trying to produce an output column of mixed types. If you show some sample data with a sample of what you want the query output to be, we can probably assist with getting MySQL to cast these appropriately as strings.

Comment: You cannot combine different data types (time and full date) in the same column: SQL is not Excel. If you don't need to do further calculations, you'll have to cast everything to string.

Comment: To me this seems a formatting issue, which you should probably do in the application level, not in the database level.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: +-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.42                               |
| version                 | 5.5.42-log                           |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                               |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                                |

Comment: I edited my question to include some data examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CAST()` to convert the values to strings so the output of `CASE` is a consistent data type.

This should work:

```
SELECT (CASE 
  WHEN DATE(datetime_column) = CURDATE() THEN CAST(TIME(datetime_column) AS CHAR) 
  ELSE CAST(datetime_column AS CHAR)
  END) as datetime_column
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thanks Ike Walker!